# How to Perform pagination in couchbase lite Database?

Tags: android, pagination, couchbase-lite

In my application I have integrated Couchebase lite database for storing 
     records,its working fine ,but the problem was i cannot get some amount of 
     data(it loas all data but i want load 20 records first and another 20data 
    next like lazy loading)
    how can i perform pagination using couhebase lite db android

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the version of Couchbase Lite that you are using

- If you are 1.x, then you use [limit](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/query/query/index.html) and [skip](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/query/query/index.html) on the [View Query](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/query/query/index.html)
- if you are on 2.0 , then you would specify limit/offset in your [Query](https://blog.couchbase.com/sql-for-json-query-interface-couchbase-mobile/) similar to example below

     `Query
      .select(SelectResult.all())
      .from(DataSource.database(db))
      .limit(limit,offset: offset)`